# Postgres - Manual Locking Clashing with Auto Vacumn

Tags: postgresql, locking

I'm working an part of a system where tables need to be locked in "IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT" mode.

The problem is that the Autovacumn daemon (autovacuum: ANALYZE) kicks in immediately on a table after it has been worked on - stopping the next process from taking a "IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT".

The tables are large so the vacuum takes a while. I could check for this before the transaction that is trying to lock starts and use pg_cancel_backend to stop the autovacuum daemon. Are there any consequences to this? The other option is to manually schedule vacuuming but everywhere you read it's best to avoid this. Are there any parameters which I have missed that could tweak the autovacuum to stop it from behaving like this?

Thanks

Comment: it seems to be working,,, you just don't like the result: What do you expect from `nowait`.  I had a similar problem and solved it by putting the frequently updated rows in a different table to the largely static rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep autovacuum from working, you will incur table bloat and eventually risk downtime when PostgreSQL shuts down to avoid data loss due to transaction ID wraparound.

Disabling autovacuum for this table (`ALTER TABLE ... SET (autovacuum_enabled = off)`) and regularly scheduling a manual `VACUUM` is an option.

But it would be best to change your procedure so that you don't have to lock tables explicitly all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - Am I right in thinking that If i turn autovaccum back on after the query within the transaction then I wouldn't need to regular schedule a manual vacuum? I have just tried this and that seems to be the case - the worry would be that we end up with tables with auto vacuuming switched off.

    `BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE schema.table SET (autovacuum_enabled = off);

LOCK schema.table IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;

-- DO STUFF

ALTER TABLE schema.table SET (autovacuum_enabled = on);

COMMIT;`

Comment: That won't help, and autovacuum will still run, blocking your `LOCK TABLE` statements. Nobody (including autovacuum) outside your transaction can see the changed setting. Besides I think that changing the setting will keep autovacuum from starting new runs, but it won't interrupt an already running autovacuum worker.

Comment: Interestingly I'm getting a different behavior. I updated a  table and checked pg_stat_activity to ensure the autovacuum is running. 

I then run:

'
BEGIN;

LOCK schema.table IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;

COMMIT;

'

and get:

could not obtain lock on relation


If however I run

'

BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE schema.table SET (autovacuum_enabled = off);

LOCK schema.table IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;

ALTER TABLE schema.table SET (autovacuum_enabled = on);

COMMIT;

'

I get a successful execution: Query returned successfully with no result

Comment: You were just lucky that your `ALTER TABLE` got there before autovacuum did (I guess). Both take `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE` locks on the table that are mutually incompatible. Autovacuum terminates when it cannot get its lock. The upshot is that autovacuum won't be able to do its job. Either run it manually, or do away with the table lock.